# Should I change my my ProgID version when my DLL version changes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, com

If i have a version of a dll (say 1.1.2) and i install a new version of (1.1.3), will leaving the progid as (myprogram.1) cause any issues with programs finding the dll correctly when the new version is installed?

Thanks

Comment: Is the new DLL fully compatible both forwards and backwards? If so then don't change it.

Comment: @ben yes it is fully backwards and forwards compatible